# Can you give an example where ROC is better than PRC for comparison of binary classifiers

Tags: statistics

Instead of using Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC), you use Precision Recall Curve to compare classifiers when you have imbalance of the classes and the class you seek is much rarer.

For example, if you have million people to be tested for a certain rare disease, there are two methods for testing, and there are actually only 100 people in that million that are ill, you can get the following results:

Method 1: 100 people test positive, 90 of which actually have the disease.

Method 2: 1000 people test positive, 90 of which actually have the disease.

Method 1: TP=90; FN=10; FP=10; TN=999890;

Which gives: 
Sensitivity/Recall/TPR: 0.9; Specificity: ~0.9999; FPR: ~0.0001;

Precision: 0.9

Method 2: TP=90; FN=10; FP=910; TN=998990;

Which gives: 
Sensitivity/Recall/TPR: 0.9; Specificity: ~0.9990 FPR: ~0.0010

Precision: 0.09

So the actual points on the ROC will be quite near to each other for both methods, but if we use PRC, they will be quite apart and it seems that PRC is more "informative" in this case.

But can you give similar example where ROC is better than PRC / respectively sensitivity and specificity are better than precision recall? 
Or maybe point to an example why is bad to ignore TN (as PRC calculations do)?